# Can We host JavaScript files of our SharePoint framework CSOM solution in the Workflow manger dedicated Server?

Tags: javascript, workflow-manager, cdn

We are developing a custom solution using SharePoint (2016) Framework. So to deploy the solution:

1. We put solution in the app catalog. 2. We need to host JavaScript files.

We don't want to use Azure CDN for JavaScript file hosting. We don't want to use stand alone local server just to host JavaScript files.

We are going to install Workflow Manager on a dedicated Server. Can that Workflow Manager also host JavaScript files?

This way our workflow manager server does two jobs:

1. Service workflows.
2. Processes JavaScript files as a dedicated Server and hence eliminate the need for Azure CDN.

Thanks,

Tom Chaudhry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can host your JavaScript files anywhere you like, as long as your users can access them. So as long as the workflow manager is running the `IIS role`, sure, you can provision a web application and put your JavaScript files there and as long as your users can authenticate to it (or it allows anonymous) that's your 'CDN'.  You can also just use a SharePoint document library as your 'CDN'. You may have to give Everyone read access to the library and/or site, but then the document library is your 'CDN'. You certainly don't need to use `Azure CDN`.